# nodejs mongoDB connection management failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connection, pool

I think nodejs mongoDB does a good connection close for each API request, but the connection increases explosively and the server often stops. Please refer to the code and connection graph below. Thank you.

```
async function searchDb(queryObj) {
    return await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const client = new MongoClient(
            mongoUri, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        });

        try {
            await client.connect();
            const database = client.db(mongoDB);            // ex) m2n
            const coll = database.collection(collection);   // ex) questions3
            const result = await coll.find(queryObj).toArray();
            resolve(result);

        } catch (error) {
            reject(console.log(`search question error : ${error}`));

        } finally {
            console.log("Closed successfully to server ++");
            await client.close();
        }
    })
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uBXm.png)

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/troubleshoot-connection/#too-many-open-connections-to-your-database-deployment

I found the above site and applied it to the code, but the situation didn't improve, and I asked the cloud.mongodb.com chatbot, but I waited a long time and didn't get a response.

Comment: if you are using a server for query, You can apply singleton connection. Your function will not create a new connection when searchDb is called. You create a connection and all your function use it.